# iOS NSNumber intValue EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, nsnumber

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  int num = 5;
      [viewController functionA:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num-1]];

}

-(void) functionA: (NSNumber*) indexNumber{

    int hi = [indexNumber intValue];

}
```

viewController is an instance of a custom UIViewController class. functionA is a function in that class. touchesEnded is in another class.

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. After searching online it seems it might be a release/alloc error, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: numberWithInt looks like it returns an autorelease'd value.  Can you call retain, or are you using ARC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, 2 things:

1. You never have explicit ownership of your NSNumber, which is irrelevant, because
2. viewController is most likely nil.  Why would you reference a class like that if you could just use self and save yourself some extra characters?  If the function truly is in another class, check that you have even allocated and initialized it before you go running about and calling methods.  Your crash might have more to do with said extra class than with your NSNumber.

Comment: When I went step by step in the debugger, it successfully called function A. It just crashed with it tried to execute the intValue function.

Comment: Put an NSLog line before the intValue call in the method and check that the indexNumber variable is not nil.

Comment: I did that and it was not nil.

Comment: So check if it's int value is nil.

Comment: @CodaFi Messages to nil always return nil without crashing. `-[NSNumber intValue]` will return `nil`/0 when sent to `nil`. The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: My thing is that he stepped through his code and found that that was where it was crashing.  From what I can see, his methods are legitimate.  He could be withholding something.  And costique, NSNumber would return a NULL pointer and crash with a message sent to dealloced instance message.

Comment: Because %@ is the literal for a string or an object.  You want %i for int

Comment: I thought you use %@ for NSNumber since its an object. It doesn't crash any more when I use %i, but I get really weird numbers that randomly change on each execution.

Comment: Those are it's location in memory.  It should change.  At least you have the numbers... Your code is crashing somewhere else.  Reveal the whole class with an edit.